# Ruby/IMAP getting messages starting from the last saved mesage uid

Tags: ruby, imap, uid

I'm trying to get new messages starting from the last saved message id of a folder.

Here's my code so far:

```
self.imap_connection.examine(folder)
imap_query = "UID SEARCH #{last_uid}:*"
messages = self.imap_connection.search(imap_query)
```

The only response I'm getting from the IMAP server is:
Error in IMAP command received by server.

So, does anyone know the correct "syntax" for the ruby imap library to get the uids ??

Regards, Alex

Answer (score 2):

Getting all the messages after a certain last fetched UID works for me.

> imap_connection.uid_search(["UID", "#{last_fetched_uid + 1}:#{MAX_UID}"])

Comment: I tried this and it gives me the error: Net::IMAP::BadResponseError: Could not parse command

Comment: Try using a number instead of * in place of MAX_UID

Answer (score 0):

The solution is getting all messages of a folder by it's uid and saving it's seqno(it's an imap field):

```
imap_connection.uid_search("ALL")
```

For getting new mails search using the last saved seqno:

```
imap_connection.uid_search("#{seqno.to_i}:*")
```

Searching via the last saved uid did not work for me so I used the last saved seqno and voila.